# Heroku 'process exited with status 0' error on deploying Node App

Tags: node.js, heroku

When I deploy my Nodejs App on Heroku, it gives the following error: '**process exited with status 0**'

**Full Error:**

```
State changed from crashed to starting
2019-10-18T18:37:06.073668+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `: node server.js`
2019-10-18T18:37:08.520105+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2019-10-18T18:37:08.568477+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-10-18T18:37:12.513364+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=warm-retreat-51001.herokuapp.com request_id=2a67264a-419e-485a-bb15-43e099e2c0c6 fwd="196.157.20.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-10-18T18:37:13.190661+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=warm-retreat-51001.herokuapp.com request_id=9d7e8919-1e0a-4785-b493-161ba9cfd43d fwd="196.157.20.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-10-18T18:45:25.18405+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-10-18T18:45:28.192234+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `: node server.js`
2019-10-18T18:45:31.070146+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2019-10-18T18:45:31.122076+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-10-18T18:51:21+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user ahmednaguib76@gmail.com
2019-10-18T18:51:34.32282+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-10-18T18:51:34.048561+00:00 app[api]: Release v5 created by user ahmednaguib76@gmail.com
2019-10-18T18:51:34.048561+00:00 app[api]: Deploy eafcacf2 by user ahmednaguib76@gmail.com
2019-10-18T18:51:34+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-10-18T18:51:36.159392+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `: node server.js`
```

Comment: Status 0 is a success!! It's a *nix thing. Think of it as 0 errors.